# Mysql server on docker container

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Using Dockerfile to buils `mysql-sever 5.7` image with `ubuntu:16.04 (customized)`. 
When building an image without specifying `- v` arguments,  `mysql- server` inside container starting successfully.

But for container persistency,  when using `-  v with / my own/ hostdirectory:/var/lib/mysql`,  then `mysql- server` not starting when running command,  `service mysql restart`  inside the container itself... 
Please answer if anyone has an idea about it.

Dockerfile:

FROM ubuntu:16.04
 RUN apt-get -y update && \ apt-get -y dist-upgrade && \ apt-get -y autoremove && \ apt-get -y clean
 RUN echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password root" | debconf-set-selections
 RUN echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password_again password root" | debconf-set-selections 
RUN apt-get -y -f install mysql-server-5.7 EXPOSE 3306

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two requirements for mounted mysql data directory to work:

1. It has to be readable and writable for mysql process
2. It has to either contain valid mysql data or be initialized during container bootstrap

The best way to handle both probles is to build image with appropriate entrypoint, that will ensure valid permissions of mysql data directory and performs its initialization if needed.

Please take a look how official mysql image takes care of mounted mysql data directory: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L80-L200

Comment: Mysql user in mysql container has uid (104).

Comment: Could you attach Dockerfile you use?

Comment: FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get -y update && \
  apt-get -y dist-upgrade && \
  apt-get -y autoremove && \
apt-get -y clean

RUN echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password root" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password_again password root" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get -y -f install mysql-server-5.7
EXPOSE 3306

Comment: I have virtualbox installed on mac Sierra, In virtual box i have installed ubuntu.

Comment: On top of that i have installed docker

Comment: On checking error log: mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld. Pid ended.

Comment: I've edited my answer to relate it to Dockerfile you've attached. Please edit your question and paste Dockerfile there, so it would be more readable for others.

Comment: I changed it a bit more, now it should clearly point you in the right direction.